# Deprecated property in Velocity

Tags: java, templates, velocity

I have written pretty basic Velocity template which uses `#foreach` directive. When I run it, I get the following message in the log:

> [warn] The directive.foreach.iterator.name property has been
>   deprecated. It will be removed (along with $velocityHasNext itself )
>   in Velocity 2.0.  Instead, please use $foreach.hasNext to access this
>   value from now on.

But the problem is that **I don't use this property**, at least explicitly. I just use `#foreach` loop in its basic form, exactly as shown in the [user guide](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/user-guide.html#Loops).

Below is the simple code which yields this log warning. Velocity version is 1.7.

```
final Properties properties = new Properties();
VelocityEngine velocityEngine = new VelocityEngine();
velocityEngine.init(properties);

StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
Map<String, Object> velocityVars = new HashMap<>();
List<Date> dates = new ArrayList<>(); 
dates.add(new Date()); 
dates.add(new Date());
velocityVars.put("dates", dates);
VelocityContext velocityContext = new VelocityContext(velocityVars);

String template =
                "foo\n" +
                "#foreach($d in $dates)\n" +
                "  $d\n" +
                "#end \n" +
                "bar";

velocityEngine.evaluate(velocityContext, stringWriter, "blah", template);
System.out.println(stringWriter.toString());
```

So the question is - why is this warning logged and how do I structure my code to prevent it from appearing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`directive.foreach.iterator.name` is not something found in code, but in a `velocity.properties` file. And for backwards compatibility reasons, this deprecated definition is still present in the default configuration.

The warning is displayed during the initialization of the `foreach` directive itself, so it's not triggered by something you're doing. You can safely ignore this warning, but if you definitely don't want to see it anymore, you could:

1. Raise the logging level above `WARN`
2. Write you own custom properties file, or just add from Java in the `Properties` object that you're creating, empty values for `directive.foreach.counter.name`, `directive.foreach.iterator.name` and `directive.foreach.counter.initial.value`.
3. Or, extract `org/apache/velocity/runtime/defaults/velocity.properties` from the velocity jar in your classpath directory, and remove from it the deprecated settings.

Comment: Thanks! By the way, the #2 advice doesn't work. Specifying empty strings for these properties give the same warning. Looks like handling defaults isn't the strongest side of Velocity.